# Set csv record delimiter in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter

I created a script to merge couple of .csv files, using pandas python library. All files use "\n\r" as record delimiter.
I ran into issue with one file, where in specific field, sometimes "\n" occurs. That causes for [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to count it as new row.

Is there any chance to (in addition to field delimiter) specify record delimiter? Or would there be any better solution to this?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look through all of the kwargs in [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

There is the `lineterminator` kwarg:

```
lineterminator : str (length 1), default None
    Character to break file into lines. Only valid with C parser.
```

Note that it requires the use of the C parser (see `engine` kwarg)

Given that your lines end with `\r`, which is the [carriage return character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) I would suggest using that as the `lineterminator` and doing post-processing to clean up the `\n`'s left behind.

I would think that setting the `lineterminator='\r'` should fix your problem.

Comment: Hello Grr. Thank you for fast response. I am very new to Python programming. Would you be so kind to to show an example how to implement usage of C parser with engine kwarg?
I have tried to set it without it, using lineterminator='\n\r', yet I recieve "Only length-1 line terminators supported" - I presume that is due to not using C parser.

Comment: Hmm. What if you just user '\r'? You might have to do some post processing to clean up your rows, but if you have '\n' appearing I would assume you are going to do that anyway.

Comment: Hello. That did the trick indeed. I will have to do some pre/post processing of the file itself, but what you mentioned solves my question. Thank you!